# Why would main not resolve as a symbol in my win32 C++ application on visual studio?

Tags: c++

I created a new blank win32 C++ project in Visual Studio 2010. I inputted the following code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  cout << "hi" << endl;
}
```

I get this error upon compilation: `external symbol not resolved`.

Any thoughts on why this might be? I've tried including other headers such as stdio.h to no avail. Thank you!

Comment: -1 the OP failed to reproduce the error message (a *minimum* requirement for such a question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [WinMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Win32 projects:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(
  HINSTANCE hInstance, 
  HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
  LPWSTR lpCmdLine, 
  int nShowCmd 
);
```

Comment: Thank you, what if I just want to compile any ordinary c++ application? What type of project should I make?

Comment: You'd want to create a console project

Comment: -1 "You need WinMain for Win32 projects" is incorrect in two ways. First, you did not mean Win32 as opposed to Win64, you meant GUI subsystem projects. And secondly, it is not correct that one needs `WinMain` for GUI subsystem projects, even with Microsoft's toolchain.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach I stand by my answer. First of all, it is not possible to create win64 project directly from `New Project` window in Visual Studio 2010, and he clearly mentioned that he created "a new blank **win32 C++ project**", as apposed to **Win32 Console Application**. Even `WinMain` may not be the only entry point that one can use, it is used by default for **Win32 Project** and it seems absolutely reasonable to assume that this is the case here.

Comment: @JosephH: Many people even today stand by the assertion that the Earth is flat. That makes them a bit comical. Note: the win32 c++ project type includes console apps, and gui subsystem apps, and it has nothing to do with your assertion, which is just silly. Cheers,

Comment: Maybe I need to use boldface to help people stop upvoting: this answer is demonstrably **WRONG**, even for Microsoft's toolchain, and it is in **direct conflict with the ISO C++ standard**, which requires startup function `main`.